# the missing example | pre-fetch and pre-process data using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, deep-learning

seems there many open questions about the usage of TensorFlow out there and some developer of tensorflow here active on stackoverflow. Here is another question. I want to generate training data on-the-fly in other thread(s) using numpy or something which does not belongs to TensorFlow. But, I do not want to go through re-compiling the entire TensorFlow source again and again. I simply waiting for another way. "tf.py_func" seems to be a workaround. But the

This is related to [how-to-prefetch-data-using-a-custom-python-function-in-tensorflow][1]

Here is my MnWE (minmal-not-working-example):

**Update (now there is an output but a race-condition, too):**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import threading
import os
import glob
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

IMAGE_ROOT = "/graphics/projects/data/mscoco2014/data/images/"
files = ["train/COCO_train2014_000000178763.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000543841.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000364433.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000091123.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000498916.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000429865.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000400199.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000230367.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000281214.jpg",
"train/COCO_train2014_000000041920.jpg"];


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def pre_process(data):
  """Pre-process image with arbitrary functions
  does not only use tf.functions, but arbitrary
  """
  # here is the place to do some fancy stuff
  # which might be out of the scope of tf
  return data[0:81,0,0].flatten()


def populate_queue(sess, thread_pool, qData_enqueue_op ):
  """Put stuff into the data queue
  is responsible such that there is alwaays data to process
  for tensorflow
  """
  # until somebody tell me I can stop ...
  while not thread_pool.should_stop():
    # get a random image from MS COCO
    idx  = random.randint(0,len(files))-1
    data = np.array(plt.imread(os.path.join(IMAGE_ROOT,files[idx])))
    data = pre_process(data)

    # put into the queue
    sess.run(qData_enqueue_op, feed_dict={data_input: data})


# a simple queue for gather data (just to keep it currently simple)
qData            = tf.FIFOQueue(100, [tf.float32], shapes=[[9,9]])
data_input       = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
qData_enqueue_op = qData.enqueue([tf.reshape(data_input,[9,9])])
qData_dequeue_op = qData.dequeue()
init_op          = tf.initialize_all_variables()


with tf.Session() as sess:
  # init all variables
  sess.run(init_op)
  # coordinate of pool of threads
  thread_pool  = tf.train.Coordinator()
  # start fill in data
  t = threading.Thread(target=populate_queue, args=(sess, thread_pool, qData_enqueue_op))
  t.start()
  # Can I use "tf.train.start_queue_runners" here
  # How to use multiple threads?

  try:
    while not thread_pool.should_stop():
      print "iter"
      # HERE THE SILENCE BEGIN !!!!!!!!!!!
      batch = sess.run([qData_dequeue_op])
      print batch
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- no more data')
  finally:
    # When done, ask the threads to stop.
    thread_pool.request_stop()

# now they should definetely stop
thread_pool.request_stop()
thread_pool.join([t])
```

I basically have three question:

- What's wrong with this code? It runs into an endless loss (which is not debug-able). See Line "HERE THE SILENCE BEGIN ..."
- How to extend this code to use more threads?
- Is it worth to convert to tf.Record large datasets or data which can be generated on the fly?

Comment: Looking at your code, I would guess it isn't working because `data_input` isn't defined in `populate_queue()`. When you try to use it in the `feed_dict`, Python will raise a `NameError` and the thread will exit.

Comment: There's also a race condition between the `populate_queue()` thread calling `request_stop()` and the main thread calling `should_stop()`. It's possible that the main thread will attempt to dequeue an 11th element from the queue and hang forever. The way to work around that is to use the [`qData.close()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.close) op to signal that no more elements will be added (and any pending dequeues should be cancelled).

Comment: Thanks for your time and comment. So how would the tensorflow-like code look like? Or is it not intended to compute training-data on the fly? More precise: How should I solve the race-condition? The problem is that there is no error-message at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake on this line:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=populate_queue, args=(sess, thread_pool, qData))
```

It should be `qData_enqueue_op` instead of `qData`. Otherwise your enqueue operations fail, and you get stuck trying to dequeue from queue of size 0. I saw this when trying to run your code and getting

```
TypeError: Fetch argument <google3.third_party.tensorflow.python.ops.data_flow_ops.FIFOQueue object at 0x4bc1f10> of <google3.third_party.tensorflow.python.ops.data_flow_ops.FIFOQueue object at 0x4bc1f10> has invalid type <class 'google3.third_party.tensorflow.python.ops.data_flow_ops.FIFOQueue'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a FIFOQueue into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

Regarding other questions:

- You don't need to start queue runners in this example because you don't have any. Queue runners are created by input producers like string_input_producer which is essentially FIFO queue + logic to launch threads. You are replicating 50% of queue runner functionality by launching your own threads that do enqueue ops. (the other 50% is closing the queue)
- RE: converting to tf.record -- Python has this thing called Global Interpreter Lock which means that two bits of Python code can't execute concurrently. In practice that's mitigated by the fact that a lot of the time is spent in numpy C++ code or IO ops (which release GIL). So I think it's a matter of checking if you are able to achieve required parallelism using Python pre-processing pipelines.

Comment: The reason for mimicking the queue runners is that there is currently no obvious way for let's say including non-tensorflow-like operations and more importantly skip data entries or doing advanced data manipulations. I can set this answer to accepted, since now I can see output. Can you shortly give a reference how to avoid these race conditions.

Comment: A simple way to avoid race is to run `qData.close()` after you are done enqueueing, this way you'll break with `OutOfRangeError` instead of waiting forever. Also the way your logic is setup, you are not guaranteed to read anything from the queue. Suppose you push all 10 entries onto the queue before starting to read, then your reading pipeline will skip the reading loop entirely. You could skip the `should_stop` and `request_stop` logic entirely, and raise `intra_op_parallelism_threads` to compensate for the TF threads that'll get stuck waiting for `enqueue` op to complete

Comment: I meant "session.run" the qData.close() node